# How do I Call a WordPress Loop From A Different WordPress Install?

Tags: wordpress

I have a client who has 5 T-Shirt printing companies. Each company has a unique set of designs that caters to different niches. However, on all sites, the available shirt styles are the same. What I mean by that, is that if he has a V-Neck t-shirt that is manufactured by Gildan, then he has that shirt for all sites and can print designs on it for any of the niches.

So by design, I'm talking about what is printed on the shirt. By style, I'm referring to Gildan V-Neck versus Hanes T-Shirt, etc. Each style has unique colors it can come in, thread count, weight, etc. The shirts are all purchased in bulk not to individual end users.

We've created a custom taxonomy with custom fields that allow a garment page to be populated to show the various styles. He'd really like to be able to create a page on one master site and have the WordPress loop of the other four sites automatically use the loop from the master site so that he doesn't have to input the data five time.

Honestly, I'm not even sure where to start with this, so I'm unable to show any code as to where I am or what I've tried so far. Any tips for getting this rolling would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on what you mean by a different wordpress install. Is this a multi-site install? Or sepereate wordpress installs on a single host? or a wordpress install on different servers entirely? Something you could do is to take the taxonomy's xml feed and maybe use that on the other sites?

Comment: It is five separate domains hosted on the same server. It is not multi-site, however, from what I've been reading, multi-site has been added to the core of WordPress 3.0+

Comment: something like the above would be best done with PHP + 'Options' table in your theme or plugin. v simple to save the options as a serialized array and you can update when needed or take out. or you can add terms to your taxonomy from php.

Comment: Ok. so not sure how your taxonomy is set up, but you should have an xml feed set up I believe for your taxonomy (you might have to make a template for it). You'd have to set the CORS headers for that feed to allow the 5 other sites to read it, but then each of those sites could have a function to read from that feed and output the information. 

If that doesn't sound do-able for you, then if they're on the same host you could open a database connection to the primary server and retrieve the information there.

Comment: Would only one of your sites act as the "master" source of record?  Or would your client need the ability to add/edit from any of the 5 sites and have it synchronize across all the others?

Comment: All of my ideas have been with the notion that @JaredCobb brought up, that one site is the master record.

Comment: It is correct that only one site is the master. I'll probably end up using the xml feed or accessing the other database directly since they are all sitting on the same host, but I just wanted to ensure that there wasn't a built in way in WordPress to do this before I did something like that.

Comment: Unless WP is setup as a multi-site I don't believe there is a built-in way to do it. Good luck!

Comment: @EJEHardenberg Since it is built into WordPress 3.0+ core, I may just have to research into that and figure out how to set it up as a multi-site.

Comment: If you do go that route, this thread might have some helpful information: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/share-some-data-between-2-blogs-on-one-install

Comment: Also, what about writing a non-Wordpress php script that simply copies all the relevant data from the master database over to the slave databases and then triggering it whenever something in that taxonomy is updated?

Comment: @EJEHardenberg That thread might have the best solution. I think that's going to have to be what I do. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

To make data available from Wordpress across domains, you might consider the [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin. I have used it in moments where I needed to include content from a Wordpress installation on another site.